# Close modal from within modal sub component

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, modal-dialog

I have a question on how to close a Modal from within an sub component of that Modal itself. Let me explain a bit more in detail what I' trying to accomplish here.

I have a Modal that is called from within a Component to allow a user to add a new Client to a database. Since I have several other elements I want to add to the database, in pretty much the same way, I decided to create a general Modal component and pass another component as a prop to the Modal component, i.e. a form that contains the field I need to complete to add a new client.

Below some code to explain better:

Table.js

```
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './modal';

const Table = (props) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div id='overview' className="bg-slate-100 h-screen w-full overflow-y-auto">
      <div className='flex justify-end h-20 w-3/4 m-auto'>
        <div className='flex space-x-2 h-full'>
          <button type='button' onClick={() => setShowModal(true)} className='self-center inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-green-500 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-green-600 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-green-600 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-green-700 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out'>Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='w-3/4 m-auto'>
        <DataTable 
          columns={props.columns} 
          data={props.tableData} //This will need to be retrieved from the database
          direction="auto"
          fixedHeaderScrollHeight="300px"
          pagination
          responsive
        />
      </div>
      <Modal onClose={() => setShowModal(false)} show={showModal} title={props.title}>
        {props.modal}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Modal.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Modal = ({ show, onClose, children, title }) => {

  const handleCloseClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onClose();
  };

  return ( show ? (
    <div tabIndex="-1" aria-hidden="true" className="overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 bg-gray-600 bg-opacity-50 z-50 h-full w-full md:inset-0 md:h-full">
      <div className="relative top-20 p-4 mx-auto w-1/2 h-full md:h-auto">
        <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
          <button type="button" onClick={handleCloseClick} className="absolute top-3 right-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:text-white">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fillRule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clipRule="evenodd"></path></svg>
            <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
          </button>
          <div className="py-6 px-6 lg:px-8">
            <h3 className="mb-4 text-xl font-medium text-center text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{title}</h3>
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  ) : null
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

ClientForm.js

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import Input from '../form-components/input';
import Button from '../form-components/button';
import { ValidateVat } from '../../lib/vat';
import { useState } from 'react';

const ClientForm = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [client, setClient] = useState(undefined);
  const [street, setStreet] = useState(undefined);
  const [city, setCity] = useState(undefined);
  const [zip, setZip] = useState(undefined);

  const populateVatResult = (vatNumber) => {
    ValidateVat(vatNumber)
      .then(data => {
        setClient(data.company.name);
        setStreet(data.company.address.split('\n')[0]);
        setCity(data.company.address.split('\n')[1].split(' ')[1]);
        setZip(data.company.address.split('\n')[1].split(' ')[0]);
      });
    
  };

  const createClient = async (data) => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/customer', {method: 'POST', headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }, body: JSON.stringify({
      customer: data['Client Name'],
      email: data['Email'],
      vat: data['VAT Number'],
      street: data['Street'],
      city: data['City'],
      zip: data['ZIP code']
    })},);
    const result = await res.json();
    return result;
  };

  return (
    <form className='flex flex-col justify-around' onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => createClient(data))}>
      <Input label='VAT Number' register={register} required onBlur={e => {populateVatResult(e.currentTarget.value);}}/>
      <Input label='Client Name' register={register} required value={client} onChange={e => setClient(e.target.value)} />
      <Input label='Email' register={register}/>
      <Input label='Street' register={register} required value={street} onChange={e => setClient(e.target.value)}/>
      <Input label='City' register={register} required value={city} onChange={e => setClient(e.target.value)}/>
      <Input label='ZIP code' register={register} required value={zip} onChange={e => setClient(e.target.value)}/>
      <Button type='submit' />
    </form>
  );
};

export default ClientForm;
```

How can I close the Modal from within the ClientForm upon successful submission to the database? Once the data get's saved to the database, I want to close the Modal so that I can see the Table, containing all saved records, again.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Did I choose the wrong approach by making the Modal component a general one? Or should I have chosen to create a Modal per type I want to save, i.e. Clients, Projects, ....

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have access from one component from another, the best way is useRef hook.

Comment: Hi Kamil, thanks! Do you have any examples of how I should implement this in the above example? I've been reading some documentation on the useRef hook but I' still struggling a bit to fairly honest... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After reading your code, I guess you should put as props ```<Modal setShowModal={setShowModal} (...) ``` and then use it: ``` onClick={()=> setShowModal(false)} ``` and that's all.